# Is there a period of time that needs to pass before applying for a 2nd Indian E-visa?

Tags: visas, india, uk-citizens, repeat-visits, e-visas

I traveled to India using an E-visa from 2nd - 21st January 2017, for tourism purposes. I am planning to travel to India again between 12th - 21st April, again using an E-visa, once again just for tourism.

My question: Is there a minimum period of time that needs to pass before I can apply for another Indian E-visa? I remember reading something about a minimum period of time, but I am unable to find it now, so any help would be much appreciated.

I am a British Citizen

Comment: EDIT: I am a British citizen

Answer (score 4):

No minimum period requirement, but you can only get it twice per calendar year, as stated on [the website](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html):

> e-Tourist Visa (eTV) is allowed for a maximum of two visits in a calendar year.